# Store data in TinyDB before publishing

Tags: android, app-inventor

I was wondering if there would be a way to distribute my **App Inventor** app with data already loaded into the `TinyDB` without having to hard-code everything to store all of the data at start-up of the app. Is the only way to use a `TinyWebDB`?

Answer (score 1):

Your **App Inventor** app starts with an empty `TinyDB` on first run.

What you can do is to store your data as csv file in your app, load it on first run using the `File` component and then store the data in `TinyDB` for all further runs.

Alternatively you can download the data from a server database on first run of the app, but this requires internet access. An example could be `TinyWebDB`, or a `Google fusiontable`, or a `MySQL database` or any other server database.

Comment: a quick overview here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/mitappinventortest/apps-tips--tricks/5N5-mor0NOI